# conv across dimensions matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, convolution

I have a 3D volume and I want to apply a gaussian filter (with conv) on the first dimension.
That means that I want each column to be convolved with the filter independently.
I need something like:

```
result = conv(cube, Gfilter, 1 ,'same')
```

What I tried is padding with zeros the cube's columns (to the size of the filter width) and then used:

```
conv(cube(:), Gfilter)
```

but this is too memory/time consuming !

Thanks
Matlabit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convolution among one dimension, you can still use `convn`. I assume here that `Gfilter` is a k-by-1 array.

```
result = convn(cube,Gfilter,'same');
```

Comment: one more thing... if I need to do the same but this time over the slices (horizontal slices for example), is there any way to avoid a  loop (where at each iteration I use conv(slice,filter,'same') ?

Comment: @matlabit: If it's still a Gaussian, you can filter the 3D array with two 1D arrays. If the filter is not separable, you can filter the 3D array with a 2D array, and everything will work fine.